# Display diagrams in a SAPUI5 fiori application

Tags: javascript, sapui5, directed-graph

I have to display some path diagrams in my SAPUI5 fiori-style application. I checked the [Developer Guide](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/99ac68a5b1c3416ab5c84c99fefa250d.html) and the [Explored](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html) content but couldn't find anything out-of-the-box to meet my requirement.

What kind of diagram you ask? Well at a very basic level, something like a directed graph that looks like this:

[image: Fig: Path diagram]

For the most part, I may need to represent textual data (read-only for now) using the following:

1. Rectangles/circles containing text
2. Arrows (possibly with text)
3. Loops

Does SAPUI5 provide anything relevant that I may have missed?

Assuming your answer is "no", I am looking for a third-party library that suits the following requirements:

- Can be integrated and used within SAPUI5
- Is responsive across devices
- Is open-source or at-least has a basic version that can be used without purchasing

What are some JS libraries that I can use to accomplish my task?

Thanks.

Comment: In the end, you can always use d3 and create the diagram yourself.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: in latest sapui5 you could print it yourself.. https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.vk.tutorial.VIT/samples what hirse means is d3.js its a graph library, google it. its easily integrated into sapui5